# Will a variable in a php file accessable by other php files?

Tags: php

At the beginning of a php file, I defined a variable `$id`, and use it in the rest of this file. I'm curious-- How long this `$id` will last? Will it be accessible by other php files that loaded after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this variable will be accessible by all files loaded after this file but within one execution of your PHP programme. If you would launch your PHP file in another browser, a different instance of this variable would be created for this other browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you unset the variable somewhere in the script(s), it will be available to the end of the script.
Variables defined in included (and included via require()) files will be available to the other files as well.

[This page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) explains variable scope better than tiny answers.

Comment: so, if I use wordpress, the "scripts" means entire website?

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables are, at most, scoped to the request in which they are defined. If you want them to persist across requests, you will need to store them somewhere else, like `$_SESSION`.

Comment: OP could also be talking about included files, not sure.